# Array of vtkSmartPointers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, vtk

Writing a program in C++. I have a function which creates several `vtkSmartPointers` as follows:

```
vtkSmartPointer< vtkMRMLLinearTransformNode > transformNode =
  vtkSmartPointer< vtkMRMLLinearTransformNode >::New();
vtkSmartPointer< vtkMRMLLinearTransformNode > transformNode2 =
  vtkSmartPointer< vtkMRMLLinearTransformNode >::New();
```

Outside of this function I want to have a global array or vector of `vtkMRMLLinearTransformNodes` which I can add `transformNode` and `transformNode2` to. So that later in the code I can access them in another function.

I am having trouble understanding how I would do this. It is beyond my level of expertise in pointers. Can anyone help me out? A little explanation would also help me fill the gap in my understanding of `vtkSmartPointers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vtkSmartPointers are meant to be passed around (copied), and you can as well create an array, or much better a container (e.g. std::vector) of them.

```
typedef vtkSmartPointer<vtkMRMLLinearTransformNode> NodePtr;

NodePtr CreateNode() {
  NodePtr node = NodePtr::New();
  node->ApplyTransform(xfm);
  return node;
}

std::vector<NodePtr> nodes;
for (int i = 0; i < nNodes; ++i) {
   nodes.push_back(CreateNode());
}
```

In the same intuitive way you can return a vector of smartpointers from a function, or pass it as an argument to another function.

The only dangerous thing is to expose the raw pointer from underneath the vtkSmartPointer when returning from a function. Always return a smartpointer (just like CreateNode() example above).

```
vtkMRMLLinearTransformNode* BadFooWillCrash() {
   NodePtr node = NodePtr::New();
   // do something with node

   // the smart pointer will go out of scope and the object will be deleted!
   return node;
}
```

Taking a raw pointer as an argument is quite alright.

```
void WorkNode(vtkMRMLLinearTransformNode* node) {
   // do something with node
}

NodePtr newNode = NodePtr::New();
WorkNode(newNode);
```

Just as well you may pass a smartpointer as an argument

```
void WorkNode2(NodePtr node) {
   // do something with node
}
```

This is because in vtk the reference counter is kept inside the object itself, so the pointee object knows how many pointers point to it (you can try GetReferenceCount() method). The drawback is that the objects to be managed by vtkSmartPointer must be derived from vtkObject.

Some more info you can find here
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Tutorials/SmartPointers

Comment: Thank you for the help.  This definitely filled the gaps in my understanding.

Comment: Glad it was of use :)